# Teradata export to HDFS using Spark is Failing with spool space

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, jdbc, teradata

*Hello*
I am trying to load huge(~5Billion) table from Teradata to Hadoop using spark as below:

**1. I am able to display dataframe with 20 records
2. Job is failing with spool space issue.
3. I am able to read and write small tables from teradata successfully
4. Executed all the required collect stats on the primary key columns, before running job
I am able to display output of query with ODBC connection with SQL successfully
JDBC PATH : terajdbc4.jar, teradata-connector.jar, tdgssconfig.jar**

***CODE:***

````
System.out.println(partition_query);
//Dataset<Row> partitionDf = spark.read().jdbc(jdbc_url, partition_query, connProperties);
BigDecimal lBound = getBigDecimalValue(1);
BigDecimal uBound = getBigDecimalValue(new Long("4863562437"));
long lBoundValue = lBound.longValue();
long uBoundValue = uBound.longValue();
if (lBoundValue < 0) {
    lBoundValue = 0;
    }
Long defautltPartition = configs.getLong("spark.jdbc.partitions");
Long rowCount = uBoundValue;
Long rowcountThreshold = configs.getLong("spark.partition.rowcount.threshold");
if (rowCount > rowcountThreshold) {
long factor = rowCount / rowcountThreshold;
if (factor >= 1) {
    defautltPartition = defautltPartition + (factor / defautltPartition) * 2;
    }
    } else {
    defautltPartition = 4l;
    }
String pushdown_query = "( "+ "select concat( CAST( trim(ob.id0XX_appl_src_n) AS VARCHAR(200) ), CAST( trim(ob.id0tXX_src_rec_k) AS VARCHAR(200) ), "
    + "CAST( trim(ob.id0tXX_delivery_d) AS VARCHAR(200) ), CAST( trim(ob.id0XXX_delivery_channel_c)  AS VARCHAR(200) ) ) as concat_data, "
    + "cast ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY concat_data DESC ) as BIGINT ) AS concat_data_rownum, ob.* from SDE_XXXXXXX_DATA.XXXX_XXXXBOUND_T1 ob "+ " ) as temp";
System.out.println(pushdown_query +",\n"+ lBoundValue +",\n"+ uBoundValue +",\n"+ defautltPartition.intValue());
Dataset<Row> queryDf = spark.read()
    .option("fetchSize", configs.getInt("spark.jdbc.fetchSize"))
    .jdbc(jdbc_url,
    pushdown_query, 
    "concat_data_rownum", 
    lBoundValue, 
    uBoundValue, 
    defautltPartition.intValue(),
    connProperties);
    queryDf.show();
    queryDf.write().format("parquet").option("compression", configs.getString("spark.out.file.compression")).option("escape", "\\").option("timestampFormat", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").mode("overwrite")
    .save(outputPath);```
    
*Error:
21/07/11 08:50:35 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.13] [Error 2646] [SQLState HY000] No more spool space in PRODDATA.
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:309)*
Let me know if you more details to be added.
````

Comment: If you can reduce the max lengths of the character fields being concatenated it would help. Currently the "sort key" for ROW_NUMBER is 800 bytes per row (based on 4 200-byte max fields) in addition to the other columns being carried in the spool. Or you may just need a larger spool limit.

Comment: Fred, I will try and update here, appreciate your help.
thanks

Comment: Data Size is 800GB , and we have 10TB of space on spool , also I have made they changes suggested by you, still not worked.

Comment: Then perhaps the values for CONCAT_DATA are heavily skewed / non-unique. For example, if any of the fields being concatenated are NULL then the result will be NULL.

Comment: We have removed that CONCAT_DATA completely, now we made sure their is only one PK column no duplicates , not skewed , still facing READ/WRITE problems through spark.